# pg_dump fails as a cron job in one script but not another

Tags: linux, backup, cron, database, psql

I have two cron jobs on my AWS server (triggered via `crontab -e`) to invoke `pg_dump` on specific databases.

The two scripts are identical with the exception of the target database they're backing up (`$PG_SRC_DB`). One fails at the `pg_dump` command but outputs no errors nor logs:

`PGPASSWORD=$PG_SRC_PASSWORD $PG_DUMP_PATH --no-owner $PG_SRC_DB -h $PG_SRC_HOST -p $PG_SRC_PORT -U $PG_SRC_USER > dump.sql`

I know this because I've forwarded all stderr and stdout to `/tmp/cron.log` and I get the error:

`mv: cannot stat 'dump.sql': No such file or directory`

This command happens after I've run the `pg_dump` and the `dump.sql` file should have been created, but fails because `pg_dump` fails

I've debugged for hours and have done the following:

- re-directed stderr to stdout to an error log
- invoked `export <PGVAR>` for `PGPASSWORD`, `PGUSER`, `PGHOST`, and `PGDATABASE`
- set my PATH to whatever my PATH is when I run the script manually in terminal
- use the absolute path to `pg_dump`
- use `#!/bin/bash -l` login shell
- output `pg_dump` error to a file with `... > dump.sql 2> error.log`

Both scripts work in terminal when run manually.
I have no idea how else to debug the `pg_dump` command as I'm not getting any logs from it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this happens because environment variable values are different for terminal and cronjobs. You can try to import terminal environment to script. Let's say if you are running the script under user root. Try to add a line at top of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /root/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what happened but it works now. I did these two things:

1. `chmod +x pg_backup.sh` -- I had already done this, and the script was running in cron, since I could get some output in the logs
2. run `dos2unix` on the file to transform any CR or CRLF to LF -- I'm not sure how this would solve the issue since I wrote the script in Vim on a Mac